# How would i move the most-significant 2 bytes of a dword into the ax register?

Tags: assembly, x86

Load 2222 into the AX register, assuming you have the following code to work with:

```
.data
myDouble dd 22221111h
```

Comment: If you edit your question to include the assembler dialect you're using, I can give you exact code instead of just an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 is little-endian, so just add 2 bytes to the address of `myDouble` and then move the word there into it.

MASM:

```
mov     ax, WORD PTR myDouble+2
```

NASM:

```
mov     ax, [myDouble+2]
```

GAS:

```
movw    myDouble+2, %ax
```

Answer (score -1):

If you already have the value in a dword *register* then there are two ways:

```
rol eax, 16
```

Or:

```
push eax
pop ax
pop ax
```

Comment: Based on the question, they don't, and it's only in memory.